# Angularjs Two Way Binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, binding

Hi I have a weird scenario for two way binding that I just can't sort out.  I have 3 different text input fields and a 4th that is somewhat of a concatenation of the other three.  For example:

```
Text1: A
Text2: B
Text3: C
Text4: A/B/C
```

What I would really like is for `Text4` to auto update as either `Text 1,2 or 3` are updated but also vice-versa!

Any ideas?  I'm totally stumped on this...

Cheers,
Jon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have a separator (as it appears you're using '/') it's pretty straightforward.

First our html:

```
Text 1: <input ng-model="text1">
Text 2: <input ng-model="text2">
Text 3: <input ng-model="text3">
Text 4: <input ng-model="text4">
```

Then we'll do 2 watches, one for each direction:

**From 1,2,3 to 4**.  This concatenates 1,2,3 with our separator and watches that value.  If the concatenated result changes then we update 4 with the result.

```
$scope.$watch (
      function () {
         return $scope.text1+'/'+$scope.text2+'/'+$scope.text3;
      },function(newval) {
          $scope.text4 = newval;
      });
```

**From 4 to 1,2,3** we put our watch on 4 and when it changes split out 1,2 and 3 using the separator:

```
 $scope.$watch ('text4',
         function(newval) {
             texts = newval.split("/");
             $scope.text1 = texts[0];
             $scope.text2 = texts[1];
             $scope.text3 = texts[2];
         });
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9m5CG/1/)

Comment: Wow amazing.  Thanks.  I figured I'd have to do something fancy with "watch" but I'm still pretty new to this.  Thank you so much for showing me this!